# Default core location for SolrCloud when creating a collection

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a SolrCloud cluster running for which I want to create a collection with a given configuration. Thus I just run on one of the nodes:

```
bin/solr create_collection -c mycollection -shards 3 -replicationFactor 3 -p 8983 -d /tmp/some/config
```

Now, how can I tell each of the nodes not to create the collection directly under `$SOLR_HOME` (defaulted to `server/solr`) but under a subdirectory (let's say `server/solr/mycores`)?

I know that with single Solr, I can put my core config in any subdirectory and Solr will pick it up at startup time and load it. But here I would like to keep on using the command line tools.

And I would like not to change my `$SOLR_HOME` because I don't want the solr.xml file to be anywhere else but where it is now.

Thanks in advance for your inputs!